# Make vim to show line numbers starting from zero at start up in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vim

I know that if you add "set number" in ".vimrc", vim would show line numbers starting from 1 when you open a file for viewing. But I want the line numbers to start from zero. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar questions seem to have been asked a couple of times on [so] without luck [VIM: Zero-Indexed Line Numbers in :set number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176326/vim-zero-indexed-line-numbers-in-set-number) and [Can I have vi number lines starting from 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359485/can-i-have-vi-number-lines-starting-from-0)